# SOAP serialization ignoring object but including its data members in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

I have an existing SOAP method which has a huge number of parameters, e.g.

```
[OperationContract]
public ResultObject DoSomeAction(string a, string b, DateTime c, OtherEnum d, 
     string e, string f, ....)
```

Which results in

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <DoSomeAction>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="a" type="xs:string"/>
         ...
      </DoSomeAction>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Ideally I'd like to factor out these into an object without changing the SOAP WSDL, so that the code could look more like

```
[OperationContract]
public ResultObject DoSomeAction(RequestObject request)

[DataContract]
public class RequestObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string a { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

However I can't seem to find the correct way to add an attribute to serialize only the properties of Request Object and not the object itself.

Are there any way to define the Request Object that that the resulting SOAP will end up the same?

Comment: Note: Accepted Answer does not work for .Net Core 3.1 using SoapCore V1.0.0 as SOAP middleware. Since question is generic and this answer solves the problem for .Net Framework I'm marking as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `MessageContract` instead of `DataContract` this gives you more control over the message. For this to work you have to also wrap the result object in a message contract object to get exactly the same.

Here is a sample of your objects changed to message contracts.

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName="DoSomeActionResponse")]
public class ResponseMessage
{
   [MessageBodyMember(Name="DoSomeActionResult")]
   public ResultObject ResultObject { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(WrapperName = "DoSomeAction")] // renames the element to DoSomeAction 
public class RequestObject
{
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public string a { get; set; }
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public string b { get; set; }
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public DateTime c { get; set; }
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public int d { get; set; }
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public string e { get; set; }
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public string f { get; set; }
}
```

And the operation contract becomes like this.

```
[OperationContract]
ResponseMessage DoSomeAction(RequestObject requestObject);
```

For more details on how to use message contracts check also the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts).

Due to your comment I post also the requests for both method declaration so you see it is the same.

Your original:

```
[OperationContract]
ResultObject DoSomeAction(string a, string b, DateTime c, int d, string e, string f);
```

And the SOAP request and response look like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/DoSomeAction</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <DoSomeAction xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <a i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      <b i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      <c>2020-04-05T02:04:00</c>
      <d>0</d>
      <e i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      <f i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </DoSomeAction>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <DoSomeActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <DoSomeActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ResultValue>12</a:ResultValue>
      </DoSomeActionResult>
    </DoSomeActionResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And the request and response from the message contact methods so you see it is the same:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/DoSomeAction</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <DoSomeAction xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <a i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      <b i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      <c>2020-04-05T02:03:00</c>
      <d>0</d>
      <e i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
      <f i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </DoSomeAction>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <DoSomeActionResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <DoSomeActionResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ResultValue>11</a:ResultValue>
      </DoSomeActionResult>
    </DoSomeActionResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the issue. I still see a WSDL with a complex type named after the request object, rather than a list of simple types I saw when the method was DoSomeAction(string a, string b ... );

Comment: I get exactly the same WSDL for both cases and it has a complex type that is directly the body message. Also in the WSDL you posted you have in the body the `<DoSomeAction>` element which is the complex type. Why does that bother you this is just how it is defined you still send exactly the same form of request which is what I think you are looking for. I get the same definition with complex type also for your original method. Can you explain how do you get the the WSDL without complex type? If possible post a sample of your code.

Comment: I also expanded the sample and given you also the correct solution to get exactly the same response.

Comment: I'm still seeing one extra layer,  code from your answer:  <soapenv:Body><tem:DoSomeAction><tem:requestObject><tem:a>?</tem:a>....      code using just parameters  <soapenv:Body><tem:DoSomeAction> <tem:a>?</tem:a> ....

Comment: Then you did not set something up correctly are you sure you did exactly like I posted in the answer? From what you posted it looks like you did not change from DataContract to MessageContract. Check this [GithubGist](https://gist.github.com/AlesDo/29b8c9b44ef4adc064fc1a6e218a6bf9) with full code of my sample.

Comment: @AlesD is it possible to get the entire SOAP body as an XElement for parsing using Xpath or LINQ instead of crafting an data member and drilling down into complex objects?  I have a deeply nested SOAP request and I just want to parse out a few known elements from the request.

Comment: @mtpultz For that I think you will need to implement a [Custom Message Formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/custom-message-formatters) on the service side that reads the raw message XML and does custom deserialization.